# How Opensea pull the data about contract and tokens?

Tags: opensea

I am sure you have noticed, that once we deploy our NFT to testnet/mainnet, Opensea shows all your tokens using only the wallet account. I thought it used Etherscan API but cannot find such points in the doc. Maybe someone knows how it works?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they have a perfect database. They are listening to the Transfer events. And record all of them to their database. Once you connect with your account, they show you your tokens.

I am not exactly sure what is going on the backside. But I believe something like that.

Comment: Then their database should be unlimited...

Comment: Not unlimited, just very big. But still very small compared to other databases like Google or else.